# if else condition not giving required results

Tags: matlab

i have wrote this code that detects an ambulance and execute if condition on percentage of siren and execute section 1 of code if percnt>=0.5 and execute section 2 of code in else part of if condition. code works fine so far but what i want now is that while executing section 2 of code if percnt>=0.5 than it should terminate section 2 immediately and starts to execute section 1 of code. can anyone help me how to do this condition

```
%ccc
%load finaltrainednet.mat
%a=arduino('com5','uno');
%cam=webcam('A4tech USB2.0 Camera');
%cam1=webcam(3);
%fs = 8000;
%recorder = audiorecorder(fs,8,1,1);
%recorder1 = audiorecorder(fs,8,1,3);
%%
while true
    recordblocking(recorder, 10);
    recordblocking(recorder1, 10);
    inbuf = getaudiodata(recorder);
    inbuf1 = getaudiodata(recorder);
    dataout=dataoutput(inbuf,fs);
    dataout1=dataoutput(inbuf1,fs);
    YTest = classify(net, dataout);
    YTest1 = classify(net, dataout1);
    count = sum(YTest(:) == categorical(1));
    count1 = sum(YTest1(:) == categorical(1));
    length_t = length(YTest);
    length_t1 = length(YTest1);
    percnt=count/length_t
    percnt1=count1/length_t1;
    if percnt || percnt1>=0.5 %this condition works on ambulance detection
        %%section 1
        power = bandpower(inbuf,fs,[0 fs/2]);
        if power>0.01 %this condition works on direction
            configurePin(a,'D10','DigitalOutput'); %red
            configurePin(a,'D12','DigitalOutput'); %yellow
            configurePin(a,'D13','DigitalOutput'); %green
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D10',0);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',1);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D13',0);
            pause(8);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D10',1);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D13',1);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',1);
        else
            configurePin(a,'D11','DigitalOutput'); %red
            configurePin(a,'D9','DigitalOutput'); %yellow
            configurePin(a,'D8','DigitalOutput'); %green
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D11',0);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',1);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D8',0);
            pause(8);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D8',1);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D11',1);
            writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',1);
        end
    else 
    %% section 2
    i=snapshot(cam1);
     I = imcrop(i,[30.5100 31.5100 550.9800 420.9800]);
    %i=imread('f1.jpg');
    b=I;
    numObjects=counting(b);
    %%
    t=(numObjects*5);
    configurePin(a,'D10','DigitalOutput'); %red
    configurePin(a,'D12','DigitalOutput'); %yellow
    configurePin(a,'D13','DigitalOutput'); %green
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D10',1);
    pause(0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',1);
    pause(0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D13',1);
    pause(0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',0);
    pause(1);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D13',0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D10',0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',1);
    pause(t);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D13',1);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D10',1);
    pause(1);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',1);   
    %%
    i=snapshot(cam);
    I = imcrop(i,[85.5100 70.5100 450.9800 440.9800]);
    %i=imread('f1.jpg');
    b=I;
    numObjects=counting(b);
    %%
    t2=(numObjects*5);
    configurePin(a,'D11','DigitalOutput'); %red
    configurePin(a,'D9','DigitalOutput'); %yellow
    configurePin(a,'D8','DigitalOutput'); %green
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D11',1);
    pause(0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',1);
    pause(0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D8',1);
    pause(0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',0);
    pause(1);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D8',0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D11',0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',1);
    pause(t2);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D8',1);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D11',1);
    pause(1);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',1);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',1);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`if percnt || percnt1>=0.5` will almost always evaluate to `true` because it is interpreted as:

`if (percnt is truthy) or ((percnt1 > 0.5) is truthy)`

`percnt` is truthy when `percnt ~= 0`, which will nearly always be the case.

If you want to check that two numbers satisfy the same condition you need to write out the condition twice: `if percnt >= 0.5 || percnt1 >= 0.5`

You can then define functions to do the work in "section 1" and "section 2":

```
function doSection1()
    power = bandpower(inbuf,fs,[0 fs/2]);
    if power>0.01 %this condition works on direction
        configurePin(a,'D10','DigitalOutput'); %red
        configurePin(a,'D12','DigitalOutput'); %yellow
        configurePin(a,'D13','DigitalOutput'); %green
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D10',0);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',1);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D13',0);
        pause(8);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D10',1);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D13',1);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D12',1);
    else
        configurePin(a,'D11','DigitalOutput'); %red
        configurePin(a,'D9','DigitalOutput'); %yellow
        configurePin(a,'D8','DigitalOutput'); %green
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D11',0);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',1);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D8',0);
        pause(8);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D8',1);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D11',1);
        writeDigitalPin(a,'D9',1);
    end
end

function doSection2() 
    ...
end
```

And then call the functions in your code:

```
if percnt >= 0.5 || percnt1 >= 0.5
    doSection1();
else
    doSection2();
end
```

There isn't really a good way to stop the execution of `doSection2()` *while* it is running, unless you add checks inside the function to check for the condition and then `doSection1()` if it is true. However, you can decide to not call it another time after it's finished. Note that your `pause(1)` line makes MATLAB wait for a second. Maybe you could add a check after every `pause` and call `doSection1()` then?

Comment: ok that is not what am asking am saying that when if percnt >= 0.5 || percnt1 >= 0.5 condition is not true and section 2 code is executing it takes about 1.5 minutes to complete after completion than again it check if condition what i want is that if in these 1.5 minutes if percnt >= 0.5 || percnt1 >= 0.5  condition become true that it should execute section 1 of code

Comment: @HamzaAshraf Apologies for misunderstanding your question. I have modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could put your first section into a function then in section 2 you need to call the function when percnt >= 0.5.

More on functions: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html

You might also find the break statement useful: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html

Comment: but section 2 already works on if condition and section 2 takes about 1.5 minutes to execute i want is that during these 1.5 minutes if percnt> 0.5 than it should execute section 1